# Function Module MESSAGES GIVE, how to find error?

Tags: abap, system-error

I call the FM MESSAGES GIVE into Function Module MRM_SRM_INVOICE_SIMULATE, how do I find the point where the error is generated?

Thanks

Comment: describe your problem with more details

Comment: I have a custom function module used to update the status of documents. in the custom FM there is the call to the standard FM which restores the return parameter containing the error. Inside the FM MRM_SRM_INVOICE_SIMULATE the point where I see the error message is in the call to the FM MESSAGES_GIVE. How can I identify the point that generates the message?

Comment: Give the full coding, the whole architecture seems to be wrong

Comment: The code to post is too long, I would need to know how to intercept the data entry of the XMSEG table present in the FM MESSAGES_GIVE.

Answer (score 1):

Further data is needed to give you appropriate help.

But have you already tried to add a breakpoint in the `MESSAGE` statement?

To do this:

- Open debugger via `/h` + action
- then in menu `Breakpoints -> Breakpoint at -> Breakpoint at statement [Shift+F5]`
  [image: ABAP debugger: how to place Breakpoint at statement]
- in the pop-up window grid, write `MESSAGE` in the first line and then click Ok.
  [image: ABAP debugger: Breakpoint at statement confirmation pop-up]
- after that, you need to replicate the error and the debugger will stop in **EVERY** `MESSAGE` statement reached in runtime.

*Note: there may be **many** `MESSAGE` statements reached. Yo need to check one by one using `F8` key.*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I set the breakpoint at message 'KI' '222' 'E', but the internal XMSEG table is valued without passing through any point

Answer (score 0):

Extract the message ID `MSGID` and message number `MSGNO` from the list of messages as displayed.

Then try the following:

1. Try to find the place where the message was triggered by static code analysis: In transaction `SE91`, navigate to the message given by `MSGID` and `MSGNO`, then perform a Where-Used-List for the single message. This will give you the code places where that message is issued. Put a breakpoint at each place and repeat the transaction that leads to the message. The system should stop at the point where the message is issued.
2. Some developers issue their messages dynamically (with variables for `MSGID` and `MSGNO`), so that the points where they are issued cannot be found by static code analysis. This is bad, but there is another way to find it. The breakpoint at statement `MESSAGE` as described in the answer of @cape_bsas usually stops too often, but you can put a watchpoint on the field `SY-MSGNO`, instructing the debugger to stop as soon as `SY-MSGNO` assumes the given message number.